# Model-First View

Tags: entity-framework, ef-model-first

Is there a more elegant way to maintain a view in Model-First Entity Framework? There's plenty of discussion regarding how to do this using Migrations in Code-First, but of course Migrations are not available when using Model-First.

My current approach:

1. Run "Generate Database from Model..."
2. Run the created script
3. Delete the table EF generates for the view
4. Create the view manually

The last two steps are done in a post-script, of course.

I'm not expecting an integrated view-designer (although I think that's what MS was originally intending for future releases, before they fell in love with Code-First). For example, if it's possible simply to tell EF not to create that table, it would be a small improvement.

Comment: The new `CreateView` method for Code-First is especially frustrating for a Model-First holdout.